# Error when trying to use omnipay in sylius

Tags: symfony, sylius, omnipay

I am trying to use omnipay with sylius payum bundle. When i try to browse my application i am getting the following

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Payum\Bundle\PayumBundle\DependencyInjection\Factory\Payment\OmnipayPaymentFactory::getSupportedGateways()
>   in

Any suggestion on what i am doing wrong?

Thanks
Yousuf.

Answer (score 0):

If you install the latest version of Sylius from Master, you should not get this problem.  If you take a look at the method mentioned: 
https://github.com/omnipay/common/blob/v2.0.0/src/Omnipay/Common/GatewayFactory.php#L87

you can see it is not a static method anymore.

An example of these methods being used previously is in:

https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundle/blob/948f3af14bb923463cdfb7d11d49b7103333c6ef/DependencyInjection/Factory/Payment/OmnipayPaymentFactory.php#L60

which now look like:

https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Factory/Payment/OmnipayPaymentFactory.php#L59

So if you update the PayumBundle to 0.9.0, you should be ok (however I do believe there are other changes that this bundle needs so it required you to use the latest Sylius code base).